# Questions on Windows 10 and licencing/upgrading

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8.1, license, windows-10

I had Windows 8.1 Pro N on my computer, with a serial, that was from the MSDNAA programm. I was able to reserver Win 10, and when it came out, I put the ISO on an USB stick, because I didn't want to upgrade. I wanted a fresh install (I just like fresh installs). Now, I couldn't use my Win 8.1 key, which sucks!

I'm getting the message, that something is not right with the key. So what I did was buying a Win 7 Professionel version. Now, when it arrives, can I enter the licence key directly in Win 10 or do I have to install Win 7, reserve the upgrade, upgrade, and then do a clean install?

Is it even possible to upgrade from Win 7 to 10 when I have a key, that gets activtated AFTER the first day of the Win 10 release?
Many questions need answers! Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

From what I've read, if the Windows 8 key is built into the motherboard, you should be able to go straight to the clean install.

If it isn't you will need to jump through some hoops, as a Windows 7 key will not work to activate 10. You will need to:
 1. Install and activate Windows 7
 2. Upgrade to Windows 10 and make sure it's activated (rather than
    using the "Reserve Your Copy" and waiting, I would recommend using
    Microsoft's download tool for the upgrade:
    https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
    3.
    Run a clean install (Windows will automatically activate after the
    installation is complete (may require a restart or two), so just
    click the "skip" button whenever prompted for a key).

What sounds like is happening, is when you upgrade it carries the activation over from the Windows 7 upgrade install, and at that point it somehow registers your computer with Microsoft's servers (I'd imagine some kind of unique identifier of your motherboard). From that point on, you will no longer need to enter a license key when doing a clean install, as Windows 10 will look up your hardware and activate itself.

Comment: Ok, I will try it, as soon as I got my Win 7 key